# source file with keys and values and use it in perl code

Tags: perl

I have a file like this saved as `/var/ldt/ldt.conf` :

```
LDT_HWADDR='00:00:00:00:00:00'
LDT_DISK='/dev/sda'
LDT_OS_ID='24'
LDT_VERBOSE=true
RUN_UPDATES=true
```

I want to source it in a way that in my perl code I could use the exact key names and will be able to do something like this:

```
print $LDT_HWADDR;
print $LDT_OS_ID;
print $RUN_UPDATES;
```

Desired output would be:

```
00:00:00:00:00:00
24
true
```

Comment: If you were to source the file from the shell before invoking perl you could use the Env package: http://perldoc.perl.org/Env.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
open(my $fh, "<", "/var/ldt/ldt.conf") || die "Can't open file: $!\n";

my %vars;
while(<$fh>){
    ## remove trailing newlines
    chomp;
    ## Split the line on =
    my @F=split(/=/,$_,2);
    ## remove quotes
    $F[1]=~s/^['"]//;
    $F[1]=~s/['"]$//;
    ## Save the values in the hash
    $vars{$F[0]}=$F[1];
}

print "LDT_HWADDR:$vars{LDT_HWADDR}\n";
print "LDT_OS_ID:$vars{LDT_OS_ID}\n";
print "RUN_UPDATES:$vars{RUN_UPDATES}\n";
```

Output:

```
LDT_HWADDR:00:00:00:00:00:00
LDT_OS_ID:24
RUN_UPDATES:true
```

---

Alternatively, use `$$var`. Note, however, that such things are very rarely, if ever, a good idea and very often lead to complications (for example, see [the link](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html) provided by @Sobrique in the comments). The approach above is much safer.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

open(my $fh, "<", "/var/ldt/ldt.conf") || die "Can't open file: $!\n";
while(<$fh>){
    ## remove trailing newlines
    chomp;
    ## Split the line on =
    my @F=split(/=/,$_,2);
    ## remove quotes
    $F[1]=~s/^['"]//;
    $F[1]=~s/['"]$//;
    ## Set the variables
    ${$F[0]}=$F[1];
}

print "$LDT_HWADDR\n";
print "$LDT_OS_ID\n";
print "$RUN_UPDATES\n";
```

Comment: I was with you until the last bit. It's a terrible plan to use `$$var`. That's a really excellent way to create some really awful bugs. http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html

Comment: @Sobrique agreed, which is why I suggested the hash first. I just included the other one for the sake of completeness. I added a disclaimer clarifying that it's not a good idea.

Comment: @roaima very good points, answer updated, thanks.

Comment: If it were just a less good way of tackling the problem, I wouldn't mind. But this approach is actively dangerous - it's unnecessary - as you note, hashes work - but it can also create some actively nasty bugs. Imagine smashing ... well, almost anything in `perlvar`. You'll make your code do all manner of extremely fruity things, and the source of the glitch will be the config file.

Comment: Symbolic references are horrible. Just horrible. Unfortunately it's what the OP said they wanted (`print "$LDT_HWADDR\n"`). If the OP can accept `$h->{LDT_HWADDR}` or `$h{LDT_HWADDR}` it would lead to much much cleaner (and probably safer) code.

Comment: I would suggest that rather than assigning to `@F` with `split` - I rather like the idom `my ( $key, $value ) = split ( /=/ );`

Comment: I know, I know. I'm not advocating them and I've never come across a situation where they're in any way better than the alternatives. Still, for the simple case of the OP's example, they will work. They just burn your eyes out when you read the code.

Comment: @Sobrique TMTOWTDI. I tend to prefer the array approach.

Comment: thanks that work very well. one thing u are missing ";" at the end of the "die statement.

Comment: also i get syntax error when trying to remove the last ' chars. please recheck it so i will accept the code. thanks again :)

Comment: @AsafMagen whoops, sorry, fixed! By the way, please don't use the 2nd approach. It is very likely to cause you problems.

Comment: im using the first solution.why did change the code from s/'//g to the current one?

Comment: @AsafMagen because, as roaima [pointed out](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209569/source-file-with-keys-and-values-and-use-it-in-perl-code/209570?noredirect=1#comment354429_209570) you might have cases like `foo="bar 'foobar' baz"` and I didn't want to remove nested quotes.